# Удаление пакетов в Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook

Для написания и тестирования скрипта на Python 3 я использую Jupyter Notebook. Хочу удалить ранее установленный модуль с помощью команды pip uninstall "название модуля". Но он не удаляется, хотя прошло времени порядка часа. Перезагрузка не помогла. Для сравнения пробовал удалить 2 разных модуля - результат одинаков.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вы на скрине пытались прказать? Как вы их видите в gui?

Comment: Как конкретно запускали pip uninstall? Если через jupyter, то попробуйте запустить через обычную консоль/терминал

Comment: Hellseher, да, в браузере

Comment: insolor, да (pip uninstall spacy если конкретнее)

Comment: Вот и запускайте удаление пакетов не через браузер, а через терминал.

Comment: еслил из Jupyter Notebook удалять, то там пишет в строке y/n. Поэтому висит постоянно процесс. Нужно удалять через терминал